# Assembly Language: Wrong Parameters JMP Code

Tags: assembly, emu8086

So I was trying to debug this activity code I found in Google that asks me to understood the code. I spent weeks trying to figure it out my own about why does the output throws "wrong parameters JMP code" at .data line. I figured that it's somewhere along the .data line or something to do with jump. Sorry I'm kind of new to assembly language and I am having a hard time and confused as it's different in programming language that I am used to. I want to know why does the code throws the error and solution to the error

```
#include <iregdef.h>
#include <idtcpu.h>
#include <excepthdr.h>
#define PIO_SETUP2 0xffffea2a
 .data
 # Format string for the interrupt routine
Format: .asciiz "Cause = 0x%x, EPC = 0x%x, Interrupt I/O = 0x%x\n"
 .text
 # Interrupt routine. Uses ra, a0, a1, a2, and a3.
 # It is also necessary to save v0, v1 and t0-t9
 # since they may be used by the printf routine.
 .globl introutine
 .ent introutine
 .set noreorder
 .set noat
introutine:
 subu sp, sp, 22*4 # Allocate space, 18 regs, 4 args
 sw AT, 4*4(sp) # Save the registers on the stack
 sw v0, 5*4(sp)
 sw v1, 6*4(sp)
 sw a0, 7*4(sp)
 sw a1, 8*4(sp)
 sw a2, 9*4(sp)
 sw a3, 10*4(sp)
 sw t0, 11*4(sp)
 sw t1, 12*4(sp)
 sw t2, 13*4(sp)
4
 sw t3, 14*4(sp)
 sw t4, 15*4(sp)
 sw t5, 16*4(sp)
 sw t6, 17*4(sp)
 sw t7, 18*4(sp)
 sw t8, 19*4(sp)
 sw t9, 20*4(sp)
 sw ra, 21*4(sp)
 # Note that 1*4(sp), 2*4(sp), and 3*4(sp) are
 # reserved for printf arguments
 .set reorder
 mfc0 k0, C0_CAUSE # Retrieve the cause register
 mfc0 k1, C0_EPC # Retrieve the EPC
 lui s0, 0xbfa0 # Place interrupt I/O port address in s0
 la a0, Format # Put format string address in a0
 move a1, k0 # Put cause in a1
 move a2, k1 # Put EPC in a2
 lbu a3, 0x0(s0) # Read the interrupt I/O port
 jal printf # Call printf
 sb zero,0x0(s0) # Acknowledge interrupt, (resets latch)
 .set noreorder
 lw ra, 21*4(sp) # Restore the registers from the stack
 lw t9, 20*4(sp)
 lw t8, 18*4(sp)
 lw t7, 18*4(sp)
 lw t6, 17*4(sp)
 lw t5, 16*4(sp)
 lw t4, 15*4(sp)
 lw t3, 14*4(sp)
 lw t2, 13*4(sp)
 lw t1, 12*4(sp)
 lw t0, 11*4(sp)
 lw a3, 10*4(sp)
 lw a2, 9*4(sp)
 lw a1, 8*4(sp)
 lw a0, 7*4(sp)
 lw v1, 6*4(sp)
 lw v0, 5*4(sp)
 lw AT, 4*4(sp)
 addu sp, sp, 22*4 # Return activation record
 # noreorder must be used here to force the
 # rfe-instruction to the branch-delay slot
 jr k1 # Jump to EPC
 rfe # Return from exception
 # Restores the status register
 .set reorder
5
 .end introutine
 # The only purpose of the stub routine below is to call
 # the real interrupt routine. It is used because it is
 # of fixed size and easy to copy to the interrupt start
 # address location.
 .ent intstub
 .set noreorder
intstub:
 j introutine
 nop
 .set reorder
 .end intstub
 .globl start # Start of the main program
 .ent start
start: lh a0, PIO_SETUP2 # Enable button port interrupts
 andi a0, 0xbfff
 sh a0, PIO_SETUP2
 lui t0, 0xbfa0 # Place interrupt I/O port address in t0
 sb zero,0x0(t0) # Acknowledge interrupt, (resets latch)
 la t0, intstub # These instructions copy the stub
 la t1, 0x80000080 # routine to address 0x80000080
 lw t2, 0(t0) # Read the first instruction in stub
 lw t3, 4(t0) # Read the second instruction
 sw t2, 0(t1) # Store the first instruction
 sw t3, 4(t1) # Store the second instruction
 mfc0 v0, C0_SR # Retrieve the status register
 li v1, ~SR_BEV # Set the BEV bit of the status
 and v0, v0, v1 # register to 0 (first exception vector)
 ori v0, v0, 1 # Enable user defined interrupts
 ori v0, v0,EXT_INT3 # Enable interrupt 3 (K1, K2, timer)
 mtc0 v0, C0_SR # Update the status register
Loop: b Loop # Wait for interrupt
 .end start
```

Comment: This is MIPS assembly, using GAS syntax.  No wonder it doesn't work in emu8086, an x86 assembler.  Different directives and different ISA.  It's like trying to compile Fortran with a C compiler.  Assembly language is the least portable language; make sure you search for an example for the right architecture (16-bit x86) and if system calls are involved, the right OS (DOS and BIOS calls).  If no system calls are involved, 32-bit examples may or may not port easily to 16-bit mode, depending on addressing modes.

Comment: Also, this looks like an interrupt handler for a MIPS kernel.  If you don't know any basics yet, do *not* start with interrupt handlers.  Start with user-space stuff or equivalent, that just calls a system-provided function to do input / output of strings and so on.